# How to save emails from Thunderbird as .eml

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird officially supports the  format .eml-file but I am not able to save mails into this format. Please advise how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

> Displays a 'Save Message As' dialog where you can select a location on
>   your local disks or network to save a copy of the message you are
>   currently reading. You can save as .eml, .html, or .txt file types. In
>   the Windows version, select these under 'Save as type:', in the Linux
>   version change the default extension of '.eml' to either '.html' or
>   '.txt' if you wish to save it in one of these other formats. (Note,
>   the only way to open a '.eml' format file in the Linux version is to
>   use the File > Open Saved Message menu selection.)

[Source](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/menu-reference)

Comment: many  thanks - i will do all you advice. greetings

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. first save the email you are writing, as a draft
2. then go to the drafts folder, right click on your email > Save as... > choose .eml file type and save

I don't know why Thunderbird obliges us to this workaround.